# Pfaff creative 2170 embroidery machine, data transfer over supplied USB cable - doesn't work

Tags: usb, data-transfer, peripherals

I have a Pfaff creative 2170 embroidery machine that I want to transfer embroidery designs to. Supplied with it was a memory card that *looks* like it's PCMCIA, but it's not. (Or it's of some weird extension of the design that doesn't fit into usual ports.) There was also this unusual cable that is designated as a "USB PC card" that connects the machine and a PC. Shows up in `lsusb` as:

`Bus 003 Device 004: ID 09ed:1020`

Also included was a CD with an installer for "4D File Assistant". When I installed the program and entered the connection details, the 'Connection' pull-down menu remained greyed-out. Could somebody tell me what could be the cause? One possible one is that the program is too new for the machine (the menu references a "3D File Assistant"). Alternatively, what other methods are there to transfer files to the machine?

P.S. I'm not sure if this is the correct place for this question; please move if it isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it works, it's just I didn't RTFM well enough. One needs to select a storage device (a disk drive, in DOS parlance) in the program, for which there are buttons in the top-right corner of the window. Once done, a directory listing will appear, giving one access to the file operations. In addition, some of the options of the "Connection" menu, earlier greyed-out, will stop being such. Which ones in particular will depend on whether the machine has a "creative card" connected, etc.

Comment: @fixer1234 I know. I've always thought that limitation to be bogus - I mean, if I've solved my own problem, why can't I tell the people about that by confirming the answer?

Comment: That's in case somebody posts an answer that you think is even better (probably not much risk of that in this case).  :-)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a proprietary "creative card" interface in your sewing machine, and a "creative card" to usb adapter. From Pfaff data sheets and troubleshooting area, it looks like it is a COM port interface, which would likely require some settings in the Device Manager of your PC. If the COM port is not configured properly, there will be no communications. Please read connection instructions carefully, or contact Pfaff support for help, they are still in business.